# Can you already publish Windows 11 UWP apps in the Microsoft Store?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-11

**Hello,**

I am currently trying to submit my UWP app, which was created with the **Windows 11 SDK** and **WINUI**, as ***.MSIXUPLOAD** to the **Microsoft partner centre**.

Since this is my first app I'm uploading and I don't know exactly how it all works, I'm turning to you guys! Because I get the **following errors**:

- You must upload at least one package. If you are using market groups, then each market group must have at least one package.
- You must provide a package that supports each selected device family (or uncheck the box for unsupported device families). Note that targeting the Xbox device family requires a neutral or x64 package.
- You must fix all package validation errors before submitting.
  ***AppNameFile***.msixupload33.9 MB
- Package acceptance validation error: The package "***AppName***.msix" uses an invalid version of the file "MakePri.exe" (10.0.22000.168). The following versions are allowed: < 10.0.10500.0; >= 10.0.10586.0 & < 10.0.11000.0; >= 10.0.14383.0 & < 10.0.14800.0; >= 10.0.15053.0 & < 10.0.15100.0; >= 10.0.16299.0 & < 10.0.16350.0; >= 10.0.17134.0 & < 10.0.17500. 0; >= 10.0.17763.0 & < 10.0.18199.0; >= 10.0.18362.0 & < 10.0.18799.0; >= 10.0.19041.0 & < 10.0.19399.0; >= 10.0.20348.0 & < 10.0.21242.0. Update your Visual Studio build tools, and try again.

Thanks in advance for the help, I am open to questions!

Comment: try the Server 2022 SDK 10.0.20348.1 as 22000 SDK is still in preview

Comment: What is the `Windows 11 SDK` that you are using?

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT he is using the [latest preview SDK 10.0.22000.168](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK)

Comment: have you tried the  Server 2022 SDK? If this works you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Comment: Microsoft released now the official Windows 11 SDK: 22000.194.210911-1543.co_release_svc_prod1_WindowsSDK.iso. Try this and look if it now works,

Answer (score 0):

The message shows the allowed version range:

> Package acceptance validation error: The package "AppName.msix" uses
> an invalid version of the file "**MakePri.exe**" (10.0.22000.168).
> **The following versions are allowed**: < 10.0.10500.0; >= 10.0.10586.0 & < 10.0.11000.0; >= 10.0.14383.0 & < 10.0.14800.0; >= 10.0.15053.0 & < 10.0.15100.0; >= 10.0.16299.0 & < 10.0.16350.0; >= 10.0.17134.0 & < 10.0.17500. 0; >= 10.0.17763.0 & < 10.0.18199.0; >= 10.0.18362.0 & < 10.0.18799.0; >= 10.0.19041.0 & < 10.0.19399.0; **>= 10.0.20348.0 & < 10.0.21242.0.**

So the [preview SDK 22000.168](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewSDK) is not allowed today as build number is higher than the allowed buildnumber 21242. So try the [Windows Server 2022 SDK Build 10.0.20348.1](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2164145), which is the latest supported SDK.